# Why is lib.exe removed from recent WDK releases?

Tags: visual-studio, wdk

Is this a bug? Visual studio 2008 build system uses lib.exe to create static libraries. I setup build environment with WDK's setenv.bat and then start devenv.exe /USEENV. Building user-mode programs and dlls works, but due to missing lib.exe static library can't be built.

Answer (score 8):

The lib.exe functionality has been moved into link.exe, type link.exe /lib for details (you should get the same help as you would if you had just run lib.exe from the SDK).

-scott

Answer (score 1):

These are the crucial bits in the WDK makefile:

```
!ifndef LIB_NAME
LIB_NAME=$(LINK_NAME) /lib
!endif

LIBRARIAN=$(LIB_NAME) /out:$@ $(LIBRARIAN_FLAGS)

!ifndef LINK_NAME
LINK_NAME=link.exe
!endif
```

In other words, lib.exe {options} == link.exe /lib {options}

Comment: i know, but vcbuild from vs2008 uses vcproj and not makefiles. do you know a way to replace librarian from vs2008 with "link.exe /lib"?

Comment: The WDK has its own build tools and build system, nmake.exe based.  Avoiding using the WDK makefiles can cause a lot of subtle problems, like this one.  Getting the compiler and linker settings right and exactly correspond with what the WDK uses is a headache too.  There's just no added value in having VS doing the building.  Not recommended, use the General + Makefile Project template instead.